# 3000 databases on one SQL standalone instance on Standard 2019 edition, on Windows Server

Tags: sql-server

I've recently got a request from a software vendor for a SQL Instance with 3000 databases on it. Testing backup to 3000 dbs with a 3rd party tool, which is using VSS, on SQL Standard 2019, had led me into issues with worker threads exhaustion. I've increased 'Maximum worker threads' to 11.000 to be able to perform successful backups. I wonder if this would cause me more troubles when a production load will be added on the instance.

Comment: 3,000 databases on a single instance sounds like a design flaw if I am honest.

Comment: If you're trying to do 3000 backups *in parallel* I could imagine this would exhaust resources, yes. Having 3000 databases is not a common setup, so I imagine the tool isn't exactly designed for it. Maybe turn down the parallelism a notch if there's an option for it. Assuming your machine does not have 11000 cores, being required to up the number of threads to that is a sure sign you are pushing the machine to its maximum load, which also means you'll likely leave no resources for queries while backups are running.

Comment: Thank you to you both. 
To me looks like a very bad design as well, Larnu.

Comment: @Larnu: Thank you. 
To me it looks like a very bad design as well and I need strong arguments to oppose to it.

Comment: @Jeroen: Thank you. 
I must stay within SQL Standard edition limits with the number of cores (24on 4 sockets and maximum 128GB of RAM for SQL instance).